# Totally confused by racket syntax - please lend a hand

Tags: function, functional-programming, boolean, racket

I am being asked to learn some racket for university and will eventually have to do some pretty complicated stuff with tree structures and data sets. I have just started and I cannot understand how this code works even with the Racket docs, google and SO.

I'm trying to write a function that takes three number arguments and returns the greatest, here's what I have:

```
(define (mymax x1 x2 x3)
    (cond
        ((and (x1 > x2) (x1 > x3)) x1)
        (else (and (x2 > x1) (x2 > x3)) x2)
        (else (and (x3 > x1) (x3 > x2)) x3)
))
(print (mymax 10 5 1))
```

So...

- I don't know if I'm using the and comparison correctly
- I'm getting the error "cond: bad syntax (`else' clause must be last) in: (else (and (x2 > x1) (x2 > x3)) x2)"
- I don't really have any idea how to return a value from a function

Sorry to be so clueless but this is just not making sense, any help shedding light on these bullet points would be a massive help

Comment: Only the very last term may have the keyword `else` instead of an expression that always evaluates to true. You can think of it as a synonym for `#t` amd since every case will be true the `cond` does not have more clauses afyer it since they are only evaluated when all previous have been false. Eg instead of ` else`  in c languages you could write `if(true)`. If there be any use for an `elseif` after it?

Comment: The `else` clause of `cond` is analagous to the the `default` case of a `switch` statement in other languages. Just remove the else keyword in the second case.

Comment: Thanks guys still confused though. I removed the else for the second case, ran and got the error "application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 10
  arguments...:"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the syntax for a **conditional expression**:

```
(cond
  [ConditionExpression1 ResultExpression1]
  [ConditionExpression2 ResultExpression2]
  ... 
  [ConditionExpressionN ResultExpressionN])


(cond
  [ConditionExpression1 ResultExpression1]
  [ConditionExpression2 ResultExpression2]
  ...
  [else DefaultResultExpression])
```

The evaluation of a conditional expression follows 2 rules

**1) rule cond_false**

```
(cond                    == (cond
  [#false ...]               ; first line removed
  [condition2 answer2]       [condition2 answer2]
  ...)                       ...)
```

**2) rule cond_true**

```
(cond                    == answer-1
  [#true answer-1]
  [condition2 answer2]
  ...)
```

This second rule also applies when the condition is else (but note that else can only occur in the last clause).

---

**Example**:

```
(cond
  [(= 2 0) #false]
  [(> 2 1) (string=? "a" "a")]
  [else (= (/  1 2) 9)])
```

== {by evaluation of `(= 2 0)` to `#false`}

```
(cond
  [#false #false]
  [(> 2 1) (string=? "a" "a")]
  [else (= (/  1 2) 9)])
```

== {by rule *cond_false*}

```
(cond
  [(> 2 1) (string=? "a" "a")]
  [else (= (/  1 2) 9)])
```

== {by evaluation of `(> 2 1)` to `#true`}

```
(cond
  [#true (string=? "a" "a")]
  [else (= (/  1 2) 9)])
```

== {by rule *cond_true*}

```
(string=? "a" "a")
```

== {by evaluation of `(string=? "a" "a")` to `true`}

```
#true
```

---

```
(define (mymax x1 x2 x3)
    (cond
        ((and (x1 > x2) (x1 > x3)) x1)
        (else (and (x2 > x1) (x2 > x3)) x2)
        (else (and (x3 > x1) (x3 > x2)) x3)
))
(print (mymax 10 5 1))
```

- an expression like `(2 > 1)` would not work. It should be `(> 2 1)`. The syntax for **function application** is a prefix syntax i.e. the open parenthesis should be followed by the function name which should be followed by the arguments.
- the error you get is for bad syntax for the second clause. `(else (and (x2 > x1) (x2 > x3)) x2)` This clause has 3 pieces: `else`, `(and (x2 > x1) (x2 > x3))`, and `x2`. However, according to the syntax of `cond`, a clause should only have 2 pieces.

After getting rid of the `else`s and making the `>` prefix:

```
(define (mymax x1 x2 x3)
  (cond
    ((and (>  x1 x2) (> x1 x3)) x1)
    ((and (> x2 x1) (> x2 x3)) x2)
    ((and (>  x3 x1) (> x3 x2)) x3)))

(print (mymax 10 5 1))
```

The program prints `10`. But note that it wouldn't work for `(mymax 5 5 5)`, so we turn all the `>`s to `>=`s:

```
(define (mymax x1 x2 x3)
  (cond
    [(and (>= x1 x2) (>= x1 x3)) x1]
    [(and (>= x2 x1) (>= x2 x3)) x2]
    [(and (>=  x3 x1) (>= x3 x2)) x3]))

(mymax 10 5 1)
; => 10
(mymax 5 5 5)
; => 5
```

Lastly, functions don't "return" values. A better mental model would be to think that their body *reduces* to a value.

```
(define (f x-1 ... x-n)
  f-body)

(f v-1 ... v-n) 
; == f-body
; with all occurrences of x-1 ... x-n 
; replaced with v-1 ... v-n, respectively
```

See: [Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html), [The Racket Reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/index.html), [HtDP](https://htdp.org/).

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this. It's the first time I've seen a programing language like this and it's totally different from other languages I've used. Cheers :)